# Has anyone seen a bitizen with Panna City Medicines dream job yet?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I've just gotten the reward for 35 decorations but it just occurred to me I've yet to see any bitizen with Panna City Medicines dream job. Or do they only trigger when you unlock the shop?

Comment: Not yet.  I have been playing a lot since the update, and I have yet to run across one.  I've added around 20 bitizens since then.  (Most of them went out the airlock, but none were Panna City).

Comment: Off topic, but how did you manage to get 35 decorations without the Emperor coming and clearing house?  The highest I've managed is 19 (I've had the decorations reset about 7 times now).

Comment: On topic, I have not unlocked the level yet, but in all of my playing since the update, I have not seen any bitizen with the Panna City Medicines dream job (and I've definitely cycled at least 100 bitizens since the update - I'm ruthless, haha)

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what happened but the Emperor did not appear to disrupt my decorations. So I actually had 2 whole days to finish my 35 decorations (after getting like 28 on the 1st day). I was prepared to lose all 28 decorations like I did my previous 2 days since I don't even have 35 floors to decorate yet. Due to the Emperor's oversight, I was able to complete my 35 floors AND the decorations :) I'm not sure what the conditions are for not incurring his wrath such that he doesn't tear down my decorations though... Perhaps he's happy with the way I decorated the place? Just kidding...

Comment: The emperor wipes decorations?  I had him do that temporarily when I turned my phone to airplane mode, but they reappeared when I turned that off.

Comment: I was wondering why my decorations disappeared...what are the conditions to force hit to do that?

Comment: I think it is a bug, to be honest.  I've had him come and "clean up" numerous times now.  Launched the game, and in the changelog for today's update: "Fixes loses of holiday decorations".  I guess the animation is for the 26th, but for some reason was being triggered prematurely. I really wish all the decorations I had accumulated would have been returned, but I will be really glad if they stop disappearing until after Christmas.

Comment: This question is protected (and my Arqade account is too new to have enough reputation to answer it), but I just wanted to let you all know that I just came across a bitizen with the Panna City Medicines dream job!  So, they do exist as of one of the recent patches :)

Answer (score 4):

Panna City Medicines now has dream jobs (as of the 1.3.0 update).

[image: Panna City Medicines Dream Job]

Answer (score 1):

I still have yet to see a single Panna City bitizen.  It has been nearly a week and a half since the update.  Either they do not exist, they are extremely uncommon, or the level is not permanent.  Given the imbalance between maximum number of bitizens and levels, I'm beginning to think that they do not intend for the level to be permanent.

Or, at the end of the cycle, there will be another update adding more residence levels.